# How to know drive letter from a batch file is launched?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to create a DOS/Windows batch file that copy files from a source to the letter drive from which this batch is launched.

So, if i run the batch file from G:\ i would like it copy from the source to G:\MyDir.
Elsewhere, if i run it from F:\ it must copy to F:\MyDir.

How to write this in Windows Batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself: i've to use `%CD%`.